# What's the difference between googledatastore and google.cloud.datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to get/put to datastore on GCE.
But,There are two datastore client libraries ;googledatastore and google.cloud.datastore.

What's the difference between googledatastore and google.cloud.datastore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good that you have identified the existence of these two idiomatic client libraries to interact with Datastore, so let me write the main differences between them:

- [`googledatastore`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore) is a **low-level client library** for Google Cloud Datastore written in both Java and Python. The clients embedded in this library are deliberately low-level and are mapped to lower RPC models used by Datastore. That way, it provides more flexibility (for instance for the creation of custom higher-level libraries), but it is also more complex to understand and use. Here you have the link for [the library in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/tree/master/python), as well as some examples on how to use it. It only supports Python 2 and 2.7 and regarding its maintenance, as of writing the [last release is 7.0.1](https://pypi.org/project/googledatastore/#history) in April 10th 2017, so it should be mostly up to date.
- [`google.cloud`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) is currently the official set of Python client libraries to work with the Google Cloud Platform. Talking about the Cloud Datastore Python client library specifically, you can access it in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/datastore). It is a **high level library** that is suitable for most users, and you can find some examples in [the documentation for the GCP](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) and the detailed documentation in [this other page](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html). It supports Python versions 2, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6, and [its latest release (v 1.5.0)](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-datastore/#history) is dated on February 14th 2018.

So in general, I would say that you can use `google.cloud.datastore` for most of the use cases. It is the one that has more documentation and examples, and covers most of the functionalities that you might consider using. Otherwise, if you feel like managing everything from a lower-level perspective, you can go through the larger learning process of `googledatastore`.